# How does Keras ImageDataGenerator rescale parameter works?

Tags: python, keras

I always use this parameter to scale array of original image pixel values to be between [0,1] and specify the parameter `rescale=1./255`.

Then when i do this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array, ImageDataGenerator

img = load_img('val_00009301.JPEG')
img_arr = img_to_array(img)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
for batch in datagen.flow(img_arr, 
                            batch_size=1, 
                            save_to_dir='path/to/save', 
                            save_prefix='1_param', 
                            save_format='jpeg'):......`
```

When I check "path/to/save" directory, I see the picture generated by ImageDataGenerator class totally normal. How that is happen? I should see almost completely black image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I altered your example a little to plot the image and to print a pixel value. It seems that the image is *automagically* rescaled back when plotted, because I did not noticed any difference between [my input image](https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/capture102.png?w=748&h=722&crop=1) and the plotted one. I assume the same happens when saving.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array, ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

img = load_img('capture102.jpg')
img_arr = np.expand_dims(img_to_array(img), axis=0)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

for batch in datagen.flow(img_arr, batch_size=1, save_to_dir='path/to/save', save_prefix='1_param', save_format='jpeg'):
    print(batch[0][0][0])
    pyplot.imshow(batch[0])
    pyplot.show()
    break
```

The printed values are:`[0.21960786 0.23529413 0.27058825]`

Comment: Yes I assume this is the case. But when I load the rescale applied image back (1_param.jpeg) and convert it to numpy array, I see values slighlty different(changes between [-2,2]) compared to the  original one. Why is that? How can we interpret this?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind now is precision/round issues. But I need to test to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

This is because when you save it to disk, `array_to_img()` function *rescale* it back to the image range, i.e. 0-255 for uint8. See [the keras image data generator implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py) for details.